# Autoscaling with Wordpress plugins

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, plugins, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have a EC2 farm running Wordpress with 3rd-party theme/plugins installed. My question is, how do I ensure these plugins/theme are installed on new EC2 instances that come up due to autoscaling?

Some options: Launch using an AMI of my installation, launch after downloading a ZIP of my wordpress dirs from S3, or mount an EFS volume to each instance that contains the theme/plugin directories.

Anyone have experience in this area ? I assume my plugin settings/config will be changing a lot, and I don't want to have to keep creating new AMIs of the 'gold copy' every time i make any change.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use EFS as a shared storage. With heavy caching for static assets on a CDN combined with php file caching you can achieve good performance. Read more: https://cloudonaut.io/wordpress-on-aws-smooth-and-pain-free/